# How to split a Number to Natural Numerals in Ruby

Tags: ruby

for example:

*input:* 15

*output:*

15 = 1+2+3+4+5

15 = 4+5+6

15 = 7+8

*input:* 4

*output:* cannot split

Comment: You need to show [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) or you're going to get downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
def natural_numerals(value)
  results = []
  (1..value-1).each {|i| (i..value-1).each {|j| results << (i..j).to_a.join("+") if (i+j)*(j-i+1)/2 == value}}
  if results.empty? then nil else results end
end

output1 = natural_numerals(15)
output2 = natural_numerals(4)

puts output1.inspect #=> ["1+2+3+4+5", "4+5+6", "7+8"]
puts output2.inspect #=> nil
```